# Using cURL to GET api data within PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I have made a simple api end point using Kimono for pulling Arkansas Waterfowl Reports and their respective post dates.

I am given the below api url from Kimono:

```
curl --include --request GET "http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=XXXXX"
```

Because I am not familiar with how to pull data using cURL, I went to the web and read multiple articles, tutorials on pulling data from an api using cURL.  I feel that there is about 1 million ways to do this.  I have spent too much time banging head on desk. This is what I came up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <?php
    $json_string = file_get_contents("http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=XXX");
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
    $title = $parsed_json->{'results'}->{'collection1'}->{'title'};
    $posted = $parsed_json->{'results'}->{'collection1'}->{'posted'};
    echo "${title} \n ${posted}\n\n";
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The api endpoint spits out the following (truncated for length of question):

```
{
  name: "agfc",
  lastrunstatus: "success",
  lastsuccess: "Fri Jan 17 2014 06:39:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  nextrun: "Sat Jan 18 2014 06:39:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  frequency: "daily",
  newdata: true,
  results: {
      collection1: [
          {
            title: {
            text: "January 8, 2014 Weekly Waterfowl Report",
            href: "http://e2.ma/message/zgkue/nnlu0d"
            },
            posted: "1/8/2014"
            }
          ]
}
```

I simply want to pull all of the data from the api endpoint and 'echo' '$title' and '$posted' linking to the attributed url('href') of each of the data points.

I am sure there is an easy way to do it.  I am missing something.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I removed your API key from the question, you should NEVER include such keys when you publish code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'collection1' is an array.

```
$title = $parsed_json->{'results'}->{'collection1'}[0]->{'title'}->text;
```

If collection1 holds more than 1 element you have to loop through them.

```
foreach ($parsed_json->{'results'}->{'collection1'} as $item) {
  $title = $item->title->text;
  $posted = $item->posted;
}
```

Comment: Here is what I now have and it works as intended.  Thank you! 
 
    `<?php


  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=XXXXX");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $parsed_json = curl_exec($ch);
  $parsed_json = json_decode($parsed_json);

  foreach ($parsed_json->{'results'}->{'collection1'} as $item) {
    $title = $item->title->text;
    $link_address = $item->title->href;
    $posted = $item->posted;

    echo "<a href='$link_address'> $title </a>" . '<br>';
    echo $posted . '<br><hr><br>';

  }

 ?>`

Answer (score 0):

one way using curl

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=xxxx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$parsed_json = curl_exec($ch);
$parsed_json = json_decode($parsed_json);

foreach($parsed_json->results->collection1 as $collection){
    echo $collection->title->text . '<br>';
    echo $collection->title->href . '<br>';
    echo $collection->posted . '<br><br>';
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

another that you did

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=XXX");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
//var_dump($parsed_json->results->collection1);

foreach($parsed_json->results->collection1 as $collection){
    echo $collection->title->text . '<br>';
    echo $collection->title->href . '<br>';
    echo $collection->posted . '<br><br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY");
    //json string to array
$parsed_arr = json_decode($json_string,true);


$collection1=$parsed_arr['results']['collection1'];
for($i=0;$i<count($collection1);$i++)
{
    echo $collection1[$i]['title']['text']."--".$collection1[$i]['posted']."<br/>"; 
}
```